# function return type as pointer why not as int ,while returning adress of a variable

Tags: c, pointers

am having a function as given below

```
int* foo() {
int temp;
return(&temp); //address of temp variable.
```

what is wrong in writing the same function as

```
int foo() {
    int temp;
    return(&temp); //address of temp variable.
    }
```

because the "&" operator returns the address of the memory location which is an integer.

Comment: why do you want to return a temp address?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using such a function? None of them look really *right* to me, since you're returning an address of a temporary variable that will get destroyed as soon as the function is finished.

Comment: address of memory location **is not** an `int` or any other integer type.

Comment: Returning the address of a local variable is bad, surely your compiler warned you about that too. Also as said the memory address is "an integer" in the sense of it being a number, but it is not everytime a C language's `int`. One can imagine a system where the address go from 0 to more that 0xFFFFFFFF, for example 0xF493F929EC might be a valid address some day, and never fit in a C `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler doesn't go by number logic. For it, `&temp` is a pointer and just `temp` is an integer and **are different types** even though both are a stream of numbers underneath.

Only a cast can convince a compiler of your logic.

Something like

```
return (int)&temp
```

Answer (score 1):

int * is not int and c is a strong type language.
You know everything in memory can be read as numbers but u cannot interpret everything as int.

BTW, return an address of local(stack) variables seems useless.

Comment: The only time it's useful is for gathering entropy for a PRNG seed or similar, and even then you need to mix it with other methods since it might not have much/any entropy content, depending on the usage case and the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The first example will return a pointer to temp (which wouldn't make sense, because temp is out of the scope, so removed)

The second example will put the address of temp as an integer **value** in the return value of the function, which only is good if you want to print the address value for some purpose.

so it's wrong for writing the second example, because then you need to cast the int to int* for it to work like a pointer.

Comment: The OPs question is something else

Answer (score 0):

This is true, but the compiler is strict about integers that denote address, and it won't let you treat them implictly as integers. Instead try `return ((int)&temp);`

Answer (score 0):

Both functions as you give them are fundamentally wrong since you return the address of a local variable. Such an address is invalid as soon as you finish the execution of your function. Just don't do that, this is **undefined behavior**, anything can happen if you try to access that object.

Answer (score 0):

int(integer type) and int*(address) are both integer values but can be of different size. Say if int occupies a byte in memory and if we returned a 32 bit address there would be a memory  overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Because a pointer value is *not* just an integer. Yes, you can return an integer *representation* of a pointer value, but that's not the same thing as returning a pointer, because the semantics of integers and pointers are different. You can't dereference an integer type, for example, and pointer arithmetic is not the same as integer arithmetic.

For example, take this program (compiled as C99):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int       x      = 0;
  char    *cp      = 0;
  int     *ip      = 0;
  double (*ap)[10] = 0;

  printf("sizeof  x = %zu,  x = %d,  x + 1 = %d\n", sizeof x, x, x + 1);
  printf("sizeof cp = %zu, cp = %d, cp + 1 = %d\n", sizeof cp, (int) cp, (int) (cp + 1));
  printf("sizeof ip = %zu, ip = %d, ip + 1 = %d\n", sizeof ip, (int) ip, (int) (ip + 1));
  printf("sizeof ap = %zu, ap = %d, ap + 1 = %d\n", sizeof ap, (int) ap, (int) (ap + 1));

  return 0;
}
```

Now, if you think of pointers as just integer values, you'd expect to see the same results for all those print statements.  However, here's the output on my system:

```
sizeof  x = 4,  x = 0,  x + 1 = 1
sizeof cp = 4, cp = 0, cp + 1 = 1
sizeof ip = 4, ip = 0, ip + 1 = 4
sizeof ap = 4, ap = 0, ap + 1 = 80
```

Even though all the pointers have the same size and representation as an integer (at least on my system), the results of adding 1 to each pointer value gives me a different result based on the pointer type.  `cp + 1` will give me the location of the next `char` value, while `ip + 1` will give me the location of the next `int` value, and `ap + 1` will give me the location of the next `double [10]` (10-element array of `double`) value.

Not to mention the logic of both your examples is flawed; when you return from the function, `temp` no longer exists and the pointer value you return is no longer valid.

**EDIT**

Just remembered something else; you'll get a diagnostic since you're attempting to convert a pointer value to an integer without an explicit cast, which is a constraint violation.  Chapter and verse:

> **6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**
>
> **Constraints**
> 1 One of the following shall hold:<sup>96)</sup>
> — the left operand has qualified or unqualified arithmetic type and the right has
> arithmetic type;
> — the left operand has a qualified or unqualified version of a structure or union type
> compatible with the type of the right;
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types,
> and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the
> right;
> — one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a
> qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to by the left has all
> the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> — the left operand is a pointer and the right is a null pointer constant; or
> — the left operand has type _Bool and the right is a pointer.
> ...
> **6.8.6.4 The return statement**
> ...
> 3 If a return statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is
> returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression. If the expression has a
> type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is
> converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.<sup>139)</sup>

Comment: And?  If you cast a pointer value to an `int`, you'll get an `int` value.  That's not in dispute.  What's at issue is the notion that a pointer is *the same thing* as an integer, which is not true.